# Does Cloud Run have an equivalent of Cloud Functions' execution_id?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

Any record logged from a GCP Cloud Function contains a `labels.execution_id`, e.g.:

```json
{
  "textPayload": "Function execution started",
  "insertId": "12mylqhfm6hy8i",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "function_name": "redacted",
      "region": "europe-west2",
      "project_id": "redacted"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-09-26T10:57:26.917823762Z",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "labels": {
    "execution_id": "1l1qb00ft6kv"
  },
  "logName": "projects/redacted/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/redacted/traces/d2f793cf6e2fb149a8ce8dc6fd0498b4",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-09-26T10:57:26.920210899Z"
}
```

This is very useful for correlating all logs from a single invocation of the cloud function because it can be filtered upon in Logs Explorer:

```
labels.execution_id="1l1qb00ft6kv"
```

I see no equivalent for Cloud Run though. Cloud Run logs *do* have `labels.instance_id` but my understanding is that that pertains to the Cloud Run app instance so will be the same for all invocations on that instance. Hence its not the same as Cloud Functions' `labels.execution_id`.

Does Cloud Run have an equivalent of Cloud Functions' `execution_id` or would I have to roll my own? If the latter, does anyone have any strategies for doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't an execution ID, only the instanceID. To have that, you can use instrumentation tools, like Open Telemetry as mentioned by guillaume at stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73851416/execution-id-on-google-cloud-run), you can refer this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q35XivJaTFs). You can also customize the app logs with a custom/random execution ID (similar of what OT does).

Also Have a look at this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57557884/how-do-i-correlate-request-logs-in-cloud-run) & [link2](https://gbostoen.medium.com/tracing-gives-you-great-insights-into-certain-bottlenecks-within-your-application-da0f32e96d7d) which might help